# How can i send a message from content script to popup script to appear on popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

****I am making a google extension software and i have an array i had created on content script file and i want to show its elements on popup.html where i had created a div element to include them and i want every element of array to be inside a different div.

```js
//content script

var arr= [a,b,c,d];
```

```html
//popup.html

<div class="showhere"></div>



//required popup.html to be

<div class="showhere">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>d</div>
</div>
```

I hope i can get the solution with example, thank.****

Comment: The popup runs only when it's shown so there are several approaches depending on how you organized the interaction. Technically you can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), chrome.storage, executeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Popup Script,

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.subject == 'SOME_SUBJECT') {
            console.log(request.data);
            sendResponse("response");
        }
        else if (request.subject == 'OTHER_SUBJECT') {
            console.log(request.data);
            sendResponse("response");
        }
    });
```

Content Script,

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        subject: "SOME_SUBJECT",
        data: {
            name: "Roar"
        }
    }, function (response) { 
        console.log(response)
    });
```